# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 645.00 to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL Query which performs some division operation on a column which is of type `decimal(18,4)` and should return a value of type `decimal` but for some reasons, It is giving me an error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 645.00 to data type int
```

I am not making any conversion to the value and yet I have no idea why that is trying to convert it to int.

My query part is as follows

```
CASE WHEN co.RequestID IS NOT NULL THEN cd.ConsDetQty/1000 WHEN nis.[867_key] IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN q.Quantity/1000 ELSE q2.Quantity/1000 END AS 'Quantity'
```

**May I know if I am wrong anywhere?**

Comment: What is the datatype of the fields,  cd.ConsDetQty,q.Quantity and q2.Quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement is:

```
(CASE WHEN co.RequestID IS NOT NULL
      THEN cd.ConsDetQty/1000
      WHEN nis.[867_key] IS NOT NULL 
      THEN q.Quantity/1000
      ELSE q2.Quantity/1000
 END) AS Quantity
```

For this code to generate an error like that, `cd.ConsDetQty`, `q.Quantity`, or `q2.Quantity` is stored as a string rather than a number.  You should fix the column, but you can quickly fix the query by doing:

```
    (CASE WHEN co.RequestID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cd.ConsDetQty/1000.0
          WHEN nis.[867_key] IS NOT NULL 
          THEN q.Quantity/1000.0
          ELSE q2.Quantity/1000.0
     END) AS Quantity
```

That is a "quick-and-dirty" fix.  I do not recommend having implicit conversions in real code.  Better to do:

```
    (CASE WHEN co.RequestID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cast(cd.ConsDetQty as float)/1000.0
          WHEN nis.[867_key] IS NOT NULL 
          THEN cast(q.Quantity as float)/1000.0
          ELSE cast(q2.Quantity as float)/1000.0
     END) AS Quantity
```

Comment: I don't want to convert it to an integer

Comment: Then remove the final `cast()`.  SQL Server does integer division, so it looks like you want an integer in the results.

Comment: It threw me an arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to numeric

Comment: @Dev . . . Use the explicit conversion to `float`.  If you overflow a floating point value, you have real problems with your data.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
  CASE WHEN co.RequestID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),cd.ConsDetQty)/1000 
       WHEN nis.[867_key] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(DECIMIAL(18,4),q.Quantity/1000 
        ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),q2.Quantity)/1000 
  END AS 'Quantity'
```